# Make classes and objects of "main-project" known to "plugin-project" in C#

Tags: c#, dll, plugins, static-methods, static-classes

I have an application and want to integrate the possibility for others to write plugins for this application. My first approach was just like this:

[Creating a simple plugin mechanism](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/Creating-a-simple-plugin-b6174b62)

I also need to access the classes and objects of the main application from my plugin. Currently i am doing this by adding the whole MyApplication.exe as a Reference in the Plugin-Project and then reference "using MyApplication;".

Is there a better way to achieve this functionality? How can i use objects etc. from my main application in the plugin-project without referencing the whole application?

Actually i do not want to separate whole classes from my main application in an own dll. Can i build something like a "dummy-dll" which only makes the objects etc. for the plugin-project known without the whole implementation in it? The main implementation should stay within the main application and i need just something that i can reference the objects etc. from the main application in my plugin-project.

---

**Update:**

I tried already the following options:

- Every class that should be available in the plugin-project changed to partial classes. Then i created a new class library project and added a copy of these partial classes, removed the detailed implementation and created the dll. I added the dll to the plugin-project. The classes were now available but when i started my main application a "FileNotFoundException" appeared which said the file or assembly was not found.
- Created a new project with an interface for every class that should be accessable in the plugin-project. The problem is that one of the classes represented through an interface is abstract (and must stay abstract) and in this class a new instance of another class which is also referenced in the new "interface project" is created. But in C# it is not possible to add an constructor to an interface. So i always get an error if i want to reference the method of this abstract class via interface in the plugin-project.

Has someone an easy explanation for me how i can access objects/classes of the mainApplication in the plugin-project?

Comment: Use interfaces.

Comment: I already use an interface, just like it is shown in the link above. But with that i am not able to "see" all objects of the main application within the plugin-project.

Comment: You could declare the classes as partial and then, in the dll, use the same namespace and create partial dummies for the classes.

Comment: Extract interfaces from all your classes you want to publish to the plugins in a separate assembly, then inject your classes via the interfaces in the plugins.

Answer (score 0):

Create a separate project that is a Class Library (so it compiles to a DLL). Now for every object/class from the main project that you want access to create an interface and add it to this project. Now the plugin only needs to reference the interface project (dll) to know how your classes look.

Comment: Do you mean for each class from the main project an interface with the same name and the same methods?

Comment: Yes. If you do not want the class to be available to the plugins though, you do not have to add an interface for it

Comment: But the separate project with the interfaces should be in the same solution like the main application?

Comment: Yes, it can be in the main solution. It will compile to a separate DLL that your plugin can reference

Comment: One of the classes is a static class. In C# i can't define a static interface so i am not able to make an interface for that class... :(

Comment: Either make it non-static so that you can create an interface for it or move it into the "shared" dll project.

Comment: Unfortunately, both not possible. It has to be static and i can't move it completeley to the shared dll because in this class i create a new instance of a class which i refer in the new "interface project" and interfaces don't have constructors etc...

Comment: Maybe i have a workaround now. But i have another question. How do i "connect" this all together now? Do i need a reference to the "interface project" in my main application?

Comment: Yes, you need to reference the class library project in your main project so that it has access to the interfaces. And then add the you can reference the dll in your plugins so they have access to the interfaces as well